# How to find element for below html which is an error message("Hmm, try again. That's not a valid email.")

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was able to identify the error message "Hmm, try again. That's not a valid email." location using following `xpath-//*[@id='login-form']//div[1]/p` but Im unable to get the text using gettext method to compare the actual versus expected result.Please let me know how to get the error message

```
<form id="login-form" class="form-signin row ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid submitted" _ngcontent-eda-3=""  novalidate="" role="form">
    <div class="form-group"  _ngcontent-eda-3="">
    <ra-input class="ng-invalid"  _ngcontent-eda-3=""  _nghost-eda-5="">
    <div _ngcontent-eda-3="">
    <div _ngcontent-eda-3="">
    <p class="ng-invalid" _ngcontent-eda-3=""> Hmm, try again. That's not a valid email.
   </p>
```

Comment: I would try a CSS selector, "p.ng-invalid", to locate the element. How do you know you have the right element if you can't get the text?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have displayed in the question, the xpath you have written is not pointing to the desired paragraph(p) tag.
The correct xpath is:-

//*[@id='login-form']/descendant::p[1] or simply //*[@id='login-form']//p

so use it like

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-form']/descendant::p[1]")).getText();